# Проблема cron с логами

Tags: ubuntu, cron

Есть некая программа, которая время от времени должна выполняться через cron. Её вывод нужно отправить в лог файл. Для этого в конфиг cron-а была добавлена строка:

```
*/1 *     * * *       root        /opt/program.pl > /var/log/program.log
```

В один прекрасный день обнаружилось, что часть выводимой информации теряется и в логе ее нет. В частности, сообщения о проблемах и ошибках запуска программы. Если запустить программу вручную из консоли, то видны все сообщения, а когда через cron - почему-то часть информации теряется. Почему и как это исправить?

Comment: Слишком мало информации. Вполне может оказаться, что программа сама хочет менять выводимую информацию в зависимости от того, каким способом её запускают. Или как вариант она работает дольше минуты и из-за этого несколько копий программы затирают логи друг друга. Нужен воспроизводимый пример проблемы, что ли

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ возможно вы еще подскажите как сделать чтобы логи не перетирались при том условии что программа все же должна запускаться каждую минуту

Comment: `stderr` поменялся?

Answer (score 2):

1. "/opt/program.pl > /var/log/program.log" -
   просто будет перезаписывать по крону тот файл ...

> ">>" - Дописывать в конец файла ....  (чтобы логи не перетирались)

```
*/1 *     * * *       root        /opt/program.pl >> /var/log/program.log
```